# Why is the red light not lighting up?

Tags: c++, arduino, led, circuit

So I am very new to this IoT stuff and what I am trying to create here is somewhat like traffic violation detection.

My idea is: when the red light is on and if the PIR sensor detects movement, the buzzer/LED turns on.

Here's the image:

[image]

Here's what the code looks like:

```cpp
int pir = 2;
int rojo = 12; 
int amarillo = 11;
int verde = 10;
int led = 7;

void setup() {
  pinMode(pir, INPUT);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(verde, OUTPUT); // It declares the green pin as output 
  pinMode(amarillo, OUTPUT);// It declares the yellow pin as output 
  pinMode(rojo, OUTPUT);
}
    
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(verde, HIGH); // It turns on the green led 
  delay(15000); //wait 15 seconds 
  digitalWrite(verde, LOW); // It turns off the green led 
  delay(250); //wait 0.25 seconds
  
  digitalWrite(amarillo, HIGH); // It turns on the yellow led 
  delay(3000); //wait 3 seconds 
  digitalWrite(amarillo, LOW); // It turns off the yellow led 
  delay(250); //wait 0.25 seconds
  int val = digitalRead(pir);
  Serial.println(val);
    
  digitalWrite(rojo, HIGH); // It turns on the red led 
  delay(15000); //wait 15 seconds 
  digitalWrite(rojo, LOW);
  if (rojo == HIGH) {
    if (val == HIGH) {
      digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    } else {
      digitalWrite(led, LOW); 
    }
    delay(10);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please embed the image into your post (will generate a stackoverflow imgur link, and the community can embed it for you even if you don't have enough reputation yet) https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64971238/edit

Comment: `rojo` is a *number* of an output pin (12), but you compare it to `HIGH` (`1` I presume) as if it was some input signal. This will obviously be always false.

Comment: @EugeneSh. is right; the best way to handle this is to name variables more clearly, such as changing `rojo` to `rojoPinNumber`.

Comment: @Anonymous 286 What you need to do is create a variable wich contains the statment of rojo, and you will never get the rojo on, because you turn it off, before your if so you need to do something like I posted above!

Comment: @ti7 sry I did not know this,will keep in mind

Comment: @EugeneSh. So what should I do to achieve my desired output,can you guide me?

Comment: @GonçaloBastos I don't know why but the code you gave doesn't work for me

Comment: @SteveFriedl will keep that in mind

Comment: @Anonymous286 Maybe because your val dont return HIGH or LOW, maybe its 0 or 1023! I made  a program simmilar but I dont look at your entire code, I just figured out that you need to check the value of val in the moment that led is red, so if value is 1 turn light, if its 0 do not turn it on!

PS- 0 and 1 its just exempleficatives numbers

Comment: @GonçaloBastos thanks for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```cpp
  digitalWrite(rojo, HIGH); //It turns on the red led 
  delay(15000); //wait 15 seconds 
  digitalWrite(rojo, LOW);
  if (rojo == HIGH) {
    if (val == HIGH) {
      digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    } else {
      digitalWrite(led, LOW); 
    }
    delay(10);
  }
```

First of all, `rojo` is a pin number, not a value you want to use in this compare.

Second, during your delay `delay(15000)`, the code stops running, so movement is not detected during this time.

The only way to detect during the 15s delay is by using `millis()` for your timing and delay (or using an interrupt).

You could try something like this (untested):

```cpp
digitalWrite(rojo, HIGH); //It turns on the red led 
unsigned long int redStartTime = millis();
while (millis() - redStartTime <= 15000) {
  delay(100);
  int val = digitalRead(pir);
  if (val == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(led, LOW); 
  }
}
digitalWrite(rojo, LOW);
```

I didn't test this, but you get the idea.

Note that I don't know if the motion detector returns `HIGH` or `LOW` when something moves; you may need to change the code there.

Comment: Thank you so much dude this worked..... thanks once again

Comment: Just wanted to ask one thing when I replaced it with piezo buzzer it still switches on but no voice,why?

Comment: There are active and passive buzzers; active buzzers only need a voltage to make a sound, passive buzzers need a signal or tone to drive them, much like a loudspeaker. Maybe you have a passive buzzer?

Comment: Is there any way to check it? And if it is passive what do I need to change I tried using tone(led, 440,200) inside the if statement but doesn't seem to work

Comment: I don't know what buzzer you have. If it can take 5V, just connect it to 5V and ground; if it just goes "tick" it is passive, if you hear a tone it is active.

Comment: it keeps beeping continuosly

Comment: so now what's the reason it is not beeping in this circuit...

Comment: Yes, it's active. I don't know why it doesn't beep; I would need the buzzer's spec and all your connections. Try connecting it to another pin with a 100Ω resistor in series (and change the pin in your code). If that doesn't work, try asking on Arduino.

Comment: Ya it worked in another pin once again thanks :D Btw can you give me the reason why did this happen

Comment: Either it works better with a 100Ω resistor than with the resistor you used before, or you blew up the pin you used previously by using it without a resistor; I can't tell.

Comment: I am working with simulations,do pins blow up in simulations?

Comment: I am using tinkercad

Comment: It was a joke. No idea what a simulation shows when something goes really wrong.

Comment: ahhh ok mah bad

Comment: so I added up something to the same project,the idea was using ultrasonic sensor if the distance is less than a certain amount the green light turns on allowing traffic to move on and my code is not working,can you help me out, here's the code link http://pastie.org/p/5KNHxpcDtCwH8TzL1NynYE

Comment: I did not edit the question since the original question was already answered..

Comment: Just ask a new question here, if you're stuck.

Comment: Ok I did, can you check?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the position of your if

```
int pir=2;
int rojo=12; 
int amarillo=11;
int verde=10;
int led=7;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(pir,INPUT);
    pinMode(led,OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(verde,OUTPUT); //It declares the green pin as output 
    pinMode(amarillo,OUTPUT);//It declares the yellow pin as output 
    pinMode(rojo,OUTPUT);
}
    
void loop()
{
    digitalWrite(verde,HIGH); //It turns on the green led 
    delay(15000); //wait 15 seconds 
    digitalWrite(verde,LOW); //It turns off the green led 
    delay(250); //wait 0.25 seconds
    
    digitalWrite(amarillo,HIGH); //It turns on the yellow led 
    delay(3000); //wait 3 seconds 
    digitalWrite(amarillo,LOW); //It turns off the yellow led 
    delay(250); //wait 0.25 seconds
    int val = digitalRead(pir);
    Serial.println(val);
    
    digitalWrite(rojo,HIGH); //It turns the red led 
    if(val==HIGH){             //---> //I dont know if this value can be compared with HIGH, on my programm whe costum use numbers!
        digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
    }
    else{
        digitalWrite(led,LOW); 
    }
    delay(15000); //wait 15 seconds 
    digitalWrite(rojo,LOW);
    delay(10);
}
```

Comment: Won't work; the idea is to light up led if at any time within the 15 seconds the RED led is on movement is detected; not just at the time the red LED is switched on.

Comment: @ocrdu yeah that's exactly what I want to do can you help me out with that?

Comment: @Anonymous-286: See answer. It may need some work, haven't tested it.